How do I put an icon into a toolbar menu and have it correctly sized
If I put the button into the toolbar it displays correctly.

MyImage( "square.CornerToCorner")

If I put the button into a menu it does NOT display correctly sized.
Menu( content:{
    Button( action:{ }) {
        MyImage( "cornerToCorner" )
            .frame( width: 18, height: 18 )
    }
}, label:{
    MyImage( "cornerToCorner" )
        .frame( width: 18, height: 18 )
})


MyImage() is pretty simple.  It simply returns my resource using Image( ).  Please note every icon in my solution goes through MyImage() and every toolbar or side bar button displays correctly. Changing the frame size works in every location. This is my only usage of an Icon in a Menu.
return Image( name )
    .resizable()
    .frame( width: 18, height: 18 )

I noticed something interesting.  I have a 64x64 image and 32x32 image and they show up in the menu at the original size.  When placed together with similar sized elements.  All 32x32 images show up as 32x32.  All 64x64 images show up as 64x64.  If they are mixed they show up as the max sized image.  Here is a 32x32 menu:

Edit-1 : This easily reproduces the issue with the same result.  Like I said this graphic shows up correctly everywhere else.
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ToolbarView( )
            Text("Hey!!")
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ToolbarView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack { }
            .toolbar{
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .principal) {
                    Menu( content:{ // TODO:  large graphics.
                        Button( action:{ }) {
                            MyImage( name: "square.CornerToCorner" )
                                .frame( width: 18, height: 18 )
                        }
                    }, label:{ MyImage( name: "square.CornerToCorner" )})   //.frame(width: 20, height: 20)})
                }
            }
    }
}

struct MyImage: View {
    let name: String

    var body: some View {
//      if ( NSImage(named: name) != nil ) {
            return Image( name )
                .resizable()
                .frame( width: 18, height: 18 )
//      }
    }
}

I don't see a method to include my SVG.  Since it is simple I'll include it here as raw code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><svg viewBox="0 0 108 108" width="100%" height="100%" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><defs /><rect x="36" y="36" width="90" height="90" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="4" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-dasharray="4,4" transform="matrix(1.002457 0 0 1.002457 -34.71007 -34.71007)" /><rect x="117" y="117" width="18" height="18" fill="#000000" fill-opacity="1" transform="matrix(1.002457 0 0 1.002457 -34.71007 -34.71007)" /><rect x="117" y="117" width="18" height="18" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-dasharray="none" transform="matrix(1.002457 0 0 1.002457 -34.71007 -34.71007)" /><line x1="36" y1="36" x2="126" y2="126" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="4" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-dasharray="4,4" transform="matrix(1.002457 0 0 1.002457 -34.71007 -34.71007)" /></svg>


I am not able to reproduce this problem on iOS using the snippets of code in the question. Please (a) provide a complete, fully-functional example that can be used to reproduce the menu exactly the same as in your main screenshot and (b) attach the actual images you are using to the question. Also, please confirm if this is an issue on iOS, or some other platform.

@BenzyNeez TY for looking at this issue.  I can easily reproduce this with the example code above.  Please remember if I put it anywhere else the icon is correctly sized.

Thank you for updating the question. I can reproduce the problem using your code and your image if I run on macOS, but not iOS. So it's a macOS issue?

@BenzyNeez Yes it's a Mac OS issue.

I can reproduce the problem using your code and your image if I run on macOS (but not iOS).
I think this is just an example of where the native component extracts the underlying image from your button and then shows it in a native way. It seems this doesn't allow you to apply scaling. A similar issue exists for a selected Picker item, see Problem with changing attributes in SwiftUI Picker.
I tried to find a way to scale the images being used in the button labels, such as using a custom LabelStyle, custom ButtonStyle, custom MenuStyle, .scaleEffect or Picker, but nothing worked.
As a workaround, you can create smaller versions of the images with the appropriate size. This can be done on-the-fly in code, there is no need to perform any manual re-sizing and no-need to add any new images to the asset catalog. The Image initializer that uses drawing instructions makes this possible, see init(size:label:opaque:colorMode:renderer:)
For your purposes, the simplest approach would be to change MyImage to the following:
struct MyImage: View {
    let name: String
    var targetSize: CGFloat = 18

    var body: some View {
        let size = CGSize(width: targetSize, height: targetSize)
        let image = Image(name)
        return Image(size: size) { ctx in
            ctx.draw(image, in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
        }
    }
}

Here is how your example looks when just this change is made:

I was interested to see, how an image that is scaled this way compares to an image that is scaled by applying a smaller frame, so I tried this test:
VStack(alignment: .trailing, spacing: 20) {
    HStack {
        Text("Original")
        Image("square.CornerToCorner")
    }
    HStack {
        Text("Original, frame 18x18")
        Image("square.CornerToCorner")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 18, height: 18)
    }
    HStack {
        Text("MyImage (new version)")
        MyImage(name: "square.CornerToCorner")
    }
}


The two smaller versions look identical to me, even if you zoom in on the screenshot and examine the pixels. So it seems that scaling an image in this way does not cause any more loss of resolution than the way you were doing it previously.

EDIT If the source images do not all have square proportions then you will probably want to preserve the aspect ratio and scale to fit. This is easy if you know the image dimensions and these can be found by resolving the image before drawing it.
Here is an updated body for MyImage that scales to fit within the target size:
var body: some View {
    let size = CGSize(width: targetSize, height: targetSize)
    let image = Image(name)
    return Image(size: size) { ctx in
        let resolvedImage = ctx.resolve(image)
        let imageSize = resolvedImage.size
        let maxDimension = max(imageSize.width, imageSize.height)
        let w = targetSize * imageSize.width / max(1, maxDimension)
        let h = targetSize * imageSize.height / max(1, maxDimension)
        let x = (targetSize - w) / 2
        let y = (targetSize - h) / 2
        ctx.draw(resolvedImage, in: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: w, height: h))
    }
}


Disappointing that this is yet another SwiftUI bug.  I just started about 35 hours (programming time) writing SwiftUI code.  I need to figure out how to report these issues.  I had already tried a 32x32 and it is cropped in my case.  I wanted to figure out this issue first since there are roughly 25 icons that I need to draw.  A slow process since I'm not an artist ;).  TY for validating.

TY for the additional suggestion.  If I understand this correctly it will require quadrupling the count of icons that I have.  My icons are in SVG and quite stretchable.   I will not take the amount of icons that need to draw and quadruple that count.   Because I'm a sad artist it's already gonna take a day or two to draw out some 25 icons.   If I'm wrong I'll apologize ahead of time.

@Keith Answer revised for better clarity

This is much clearer / cleaner TY!!  I'll try to implement that after lunch and see if works.  Is that SwiftUI or using an older library?  I'll report back after lunch about the status!

@Keith It's SwiftUI from macOS 13.0+ (try the link to the documentation!)

Perfect, I implemented this concept into my code, which is a bit more detailed, and it works and allows icons inside Menu's to be correctly sized.  TY so much

I just noticed an issue with the answer.  The aspect ration of some icons is being distorted.

@Keith Yes, your original code was simply applying a frame around the resizable image, so I assumed the source images must all be square. Answer updated to show how the images can be scaled to fit instead. Ps. Thanks for the bounty!

kk, ty I'll study that... This code won't decide where to place the object so not sure that part is needed.  I'll see what I can do with it.

Terrific, I simplified it by removing the x and y calculations creating a CGSize with the Height and Width in it then called it like this.  It works but the icon is not centered... So I'll try that next.
let finalSize = CGSize( width: w, height: h )
ctx.draw( image, in: CGRect( origin: .zero, size: finalSize ))

OK, simplifying by removing x and y failed as the icon is no longer centered and keeping x and y in centers the icon.  Who would have thunk that was required.  TY again @benzyneez
